# Java OpenCV: HOGDescriptor.detectMultiScale parameters

Tags: java, opencv

I'm still new to `image/video` processing and a part of our project includes detecting people in a video. For this I plan to use **`OpenCV`** with `HOG` and `SVM`.

Can somebody describe what the parameters for the method `HOGDescriptor.detectMultiScale(...)` do?  Specifically the hit threshold, padding, scale, final threshold, and use mean shift grouping.

The javadoc of opencv doesn't really help. Thanks!

Comment: did you look at the doc ? if you dont understand a specific parameter , ask it here

Comment: @Pradheep Yes, it doesn't include any description for the parameters. The javadoc I'm looking at is this: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/objdetect/HOGDescriptor.html